# .NET 5 fails to export letsencrypt certificate private key

Tags: certificate, lets-encrypt, private-key, .net-5

I have generated Let's encrypt certificate stored in `LocalMachine\My`. Mail server must have fresh certificate every 90 days. My program should take every 30 days last valid certificate, export keys and reboot service.

I am facing problem during exporting private key. Let's encrypt certificate is not password protected.

My error:

```
Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: The requested operation is not supported. at System.Security.Cryptography.CngKey.Export(CngKeyBlobFormat format) at 
System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng.ExportKeyBlob(Boolean includePrivateParameters) at 
System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng.ExportParameters(Boolean includePrivateParameters) at 
System.Security.Cryptography.RSA.WritePkcs1PrivateKey() at 
System.Security.Cryptography.RSA.ExportRSAPrivateKey()
```

Code:

```
try
{
    using X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

    try
    {
        store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

        X509Certificate2Collection collection = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "my.domain.name", true);

        X509Certificate2 certificate = null;

        foreach(X509Certificate2 item in collection)
        {
            if (certificate is null)
                certificate = item;
            else if (item.NotAfter > certificate.NotAfter)
                certificate = item;
        }

        if(certificate is null)
        {
            logger.LogError($"Certificate not found.");

            return;
        }
                    

        byte[] certificateBytes = certificate.RawData;
        char[] certificatePem = PemEncoding.Write("CERTIFICATE", certificateBytes);

        RSA key = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey();

        byte[] privKeyBytes = key.ExportRSAPrivateKey(); //key.ExportPkcs8PrivateKey(); // CRASH
        char[] privKeyPem = PemEncoding.Write("PRIVATE KEY", privKeyBytes);

        string privateKey = $"{new string(privKeyPem).Replace("\r\n\n", "\n")}\n";
        string certificateKey = $"{new string(certificatePem).Replace("\r\n\n", "\n")}\n";

        await File.WriteAllTextAsync("mypath\\key.private", privateKey);
        await File.WriteAllTextAsync("mypath\\key.public", certificateKey);

        // service reboot....
    }
    catch (CryptographicException ex)
    {
        logger.LogError($"Certificate error - {ex}");
    }
    finally
    {
        store.Close();
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    logger.LogError(ex.ToString());
}
```

Program is runned by user which has Read,Write,Modify,List permissions in `C:\Program Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys`

.net version 5.0.3

target os: windows server 2016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of a quirk in Windows where private keys in CNG have two notions of exportability (plaintext exportable vs encrypted exportable).  It's an easy enough workaround:

```
PbeParameters simplePbe = new PbeParameters(
    PbeEncryptionAlgorithm.TripleDes3KeyPkcs12,
    HashAlgorithmName.SHA1,
    1);

byte[] = key.ExportEncryptedPkcs8PrivateKey("temp", simplePbe);

using (RSA temp = RSA.Create())
{
    temp.ImportEncryptedPkcs8PrivateKey("temp", exported, out _);
    privKeyBytes = temp.ExportPkcs8PrivateKey();
}

char[] privKeyPem = PemEncoding.Write("PRIVATE KEY", privKeyBytes);
```